# Using cosine rule to find opposite side in triangle

Tags: trigonometry

In triangle ABC the median through A meets BC at M. Given that AB = 8 cm, AM = 5 cm and AC = 6 cm, use the cosine rule in triangles ABM and AMC to find BC. Also find  angle ABC.

I have used the cosine rule to establish :

$BM^2 = MC^2$ So that:

$89 - 80 \cos \angle BAM = 61 - 60 \cos \angle CAM$ but I can proceed no further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cosine law should be applied to $\angle AMB $ and $\angle AMC$.  For $BM = MC = x$, we have

$$cos \angle AMB = \frac{x^2 + 25 - 64}{10x}$$
$$cos \angle AMC = cos (\pi - \angle AMB) = - cos \angle AMB = \frac{25 + x^2 - 36}{10x}$$

Hence we have
$$\frac{x^2 - 39}{10x} = -\frac{x^2 - 11}{10x}$$
$$\implies x = 5$$

Answer (score 0):

Complete the triangle to a parallelogram $ABCD$ where $AD$ is one diagonal with midpoint $M$.  Then compute angle $\angle DAB=\alpha_1$ (which is the same as angle $MAB$) with law of cosine in triangle $ABD$:
$$6^2=10^2+8^2-2\cdot 10\cdot8\cdot\cos(\alpha_1),$$
similarly find $\angle MAC$.
From here 
$$BM^2=5^2+8^2-2\cdot5\cdot8\cdot\cos(\alpha_1).$$